# How to highlight multiple words with ace editor?

Tags: jquery, regex, highlight, ace-editor

I have a textarea form field. I'd like ace editor to highlight all occurrences of certain, predefined words all at once. Passing them in an array like this, does not work: `editor.findAll("word1","word2","...");` I was thinking of using Regular Expressions, filtering certain individual words. This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ace/src-min/ace.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
// Hook up ACE editor to all textareas with data-editor attribute
$(function () {
    $('textarea[data-editor]').each(function () {
        var textarea = $(this);
        var mode = textarea.data('editor');
        textarea.css('visibility', 'hidden');

        var editor = ace.edit(edit);
        editor.renderer.setShowGutter(false);
        editor.getSession().setValue(textarea.val());
        editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/" + mode);
        editor.getSession().setUseWrapMode(true); // adds vertical scrollbar


        var keywords = "word1|word2";
        keywords = new RegExp(keywords);

        editor.findAll(keywords,{
            //caseSensitive: false,
            //wholeWord: true,
            regExp: true
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately it does nothing. Maybe I am missing some sort of library? I got regular expressions working with codemirror (http://codemirror.net/), but wanted to give ace-editor a try. 
Apparently this works somehow:

```
var highlightWords = "word1|word2|word3|phrase one|phrase number two|etc";
 var keywordMapper = this.createKeywordMapper({
     "highlightWords": highlightWords
}, "identifier", true);
```

But frankly, I don't know how to put all these pieces together and make them work.
 I basically want to pass a list of predefined words to ace, so they get highlighted. If I am not mistaken, I need to set up my own highlighting rule for this and then make them work with ace-editor. Maybe someone has done this before or could give me a simple example? I tried this documention (https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Creating-or-Extending-an-Edit-Mode), but can't make any sense of it. I am not sure even, if this is the right starting point.

Comment: What happens if you use `var keywords = /word1|word2/g` (no quotes) or the same without the `g`?

Comment: @OGHaza You're a genius. `var keywords = /word1|word2/g` (without quotes) works just great. The global match parameter `g` was the crucial bit, though. Without `g` only the first match `/word1|.../g` gets properly highlighted, all other matches of the same word `/word1|.../g` have a less distinctive highlight, whereas all other words `/...|word2|etc./g` won't have any highlight at all. But why does it not work with quotes (I thought `new RegExp(keywords)` would take care of this? Anyways, thanks so much  for your suggestion. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: No problem, can you do me a favour and accept the answer I posted. As to why they don't work with quotes, I guess Javascript interprets it as a string literal even when its inside `RegExp(..)`, honestly I'm not too sure though.

Comment: Will do. This way I don't even need `keywords = new RegExp(keywords);` anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var keywords = /word1|word2/g
```

In Javascript regular expressions are not surrounded by quotes but by a delimiter (I used `/`) with flags appearing after the second delimiter.

`g` is the global flag, so the regex will be matched multiple times throughout your editor.

You can also, with your `keywords` variable from the question, use:

```
var keywords = new RegExp(keywords, 'g');
```

Comment: But how can I assign a list of words: `var word_list = "word1|word2|..."` to var keywords as regular expression? `var keywords = "/"+word_list+"/g";` won't work and `var keywords = new RegExp(word_list);` doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Hey man, turns out my answer was very misleading. You can use `var keywords = new RegExp(word_list, "g");`